# How to overlay swf files on a video

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi recently I started working with ffmpeg, there I overlay-ed images as well as gif files on videos. Where coming to swf files ffmpeg is unable to recognize that format.

I tried below command for overlaying:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i swf.swf -filter_co
mplex overlay=x=100:y=100:shortest=1  -q 15 -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-76822-g12a419d Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --
enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.100 / 57. 16.100
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2009-03-02 14:42:39
  Duration: 00:00:10.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 663 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-03-02 14:42:39
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x360, 196 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn
, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-03-02 14:42:40
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 202 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-03-02 14:42:40
      handler_name    : hint media handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 129 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-03-02 14:42:40
      handler_name    : hint media handler
[swf @ 00000098cdb9e000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: pc
m_u8, 5512 Hz, mono, 44 kb/s): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #1, swf, from 'swf.swf':
  Duration: 00:00:04.90, bitrate: 196 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 5512 Hz, mono, 44 kb/s
    Stream #1:1: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:2: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:3: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:4: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:5: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:6: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:7: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay
_0
```

Any one please suggest me, how to resolve this issue or even getting frames from swf format files by using ffmpeg or any other similar tools.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for your quick response. I added my complete output. Please check it. Thanq.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can't decode vector SWF. I'm not sure if that is what your input contains though. You should supply a sample input file.